# OOP interaction with database

Tags: c#, database, oop

If object oriented programming is focused on objects, which consist of methods and data, what is the best OOP-focused approach to working with databases, using C#?

For example, I want to log something using C# classes, and record the logs in a SQL table. All other factors being neutral, would it be more "proper," object-oriented speaking, to do:

- Create a class for what's being logged, and include methods for database access
  (The methods are tied closely to data)

  ```
  public class Activity
  {
      public string ActivityProperty { get; set; }

      public void SQLMethod1() {}

      public void SQLMethod2() {}
  }
  ```

...or,

- Create a class for what's being logged, and create a class for database access
  (Methods are not closely tied to data, but the *way* data is accessed is treated itself as an object, i.e. referencing EF or another ORM)

  ```
  public class Activity
  {
      public string ActivityProperty { get; set; }
  }

  public class SQLMethods
  {
      public string SQLProperty { get; set; }

      public void SQLMethod1(Activity activityParam) { }

      public void SQLMethod2(Activity activityParam) { }
  }
  ```

...or, perhaps a better design would be more "object-oriented"?

Comment: Read about active record, repository, ORM.

Comment: Sorry but your question is waaaaaaaaaaaaay too broad and also shows that you haven't done that much research. In general you have an object which maps to a row on a table and the methods that class contains have no correlation to anything in SQL. You use other methods on a db context object to do reads/writes.

Comment: And read about SOLID http://www.codemag.com/article/1001061

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad. They are just asking whether to put SQL code inside one class or another. You yourself answered the question in your comment.

Comment: thanks, i will do more research. i see how this question would be on the fringe of an "okay"-type question for SO. basically, just trying to understand how oop works, especially as opposed to straight procedural, when it comes to certain types of tasks. again, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, I prefer not to put database access logic into classes because it hinders your ability to use them in other scenarios in which data access is not required. So I think your second option is the more flexible one.

However, if you are already aware of ORM solutions such as [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I would suggest using one of those. EF takes an approach closer to your second one in which you use POCOs (plain old C# classes) and other EF classes take care of moving data from those objects into the database and back.

So overall my suggestion would be to use Entity Framework with the [code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#codefirst) methodology.